# Failed to load the jupyterlab-git server extension on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I have installed jupyter lab and jupyterlab-git + rebuilt it as required but getting the following well known error:

> Failed to load the jupyterlab-git server extension Git server
> extension is unavailable. Please ensure you have installed the
> JupyterLab Git server extension by running: pip install
> --upgrade jupyterlab-git. To confirm that the server extension is installed, run: jupyter server extension list.

```
jupyter lab extension list:
```

[image]

`jupyter server extension enable --user --py jupyterlab_git`:
[image]

Please advise how can I enable this extension?
I have rerun, restarted and refreshed jupyter lab / browser multiple times, without any success.

Python 3.7.13 (via pyenv), system Python is 3.8.9
Git is 2.25.1